# Custom CSS image hover-states

Tags: html, css, image, hover, hyperlink

I've run in to a bit of a problem. I have a menu list where I custom made some image hover states for list items. This worked perfectly fine until I needed to change the menu items (list item text length, etc). I have to go back and re-make all of the images each time something changes.

Here are some images of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

[image]

Basically the hover adds a red background and a duplicate of that red region rotated ~2 degrees and is lighter colored. Would it be possible to do this via CSS with `:after` and `transform: rotate()`? If not, what would be a nice way of accomplishing this effect for varying word lengths?

Thanks ahead of time!

Tre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can easily be done with transform as you say. You'll need to have two elements in each button though, one for the text and one for the skewed background:

```
<div class="menu-button">
    <div class="text">Screenings</div>
    <div class="hover-bg"></div>
</div>
```

And style the `.hover-bg` class something like this:

```
#menu .menu-button:hover .hover-bg
{
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(220, 50, 50, 0.4);
    transform: rotate(2deg) scale(1.05, 1);
    transform-origin: center right;
}​
```

[Here's an example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LukAB/2/)

[Here's an example where I had some fun with transitions](http://jsfiddle.net/LukAB/4/). Due to lazyness I only bothered to make it work in Webkit, meaning Chrome and Webkit.

Note that for cross-browser compatibility you'll need the vendor specific property prefixes (`-webkit-`, `-moz-`, etc)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I'm using Wordpress, so I used jQuery to insert a hover-bg div inside the list items to achieve this effect. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I did, however, run in to an issue with if you hover over the top of the `.hoverbg` it'll activate the back rotated div and not the link in my example: http://jsfiddle.net/heHY9/, if you could please take a look at that too, it'd be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The reason is that you have the hover effect on the link itself, meaning that as soon as the mouse leaves the link the red background disappears, even though the mouse is still technically over the list item. Move the hover pseudo class to the list item instead and it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/heHY9/2/

Comment: Ahh. So easy. I was playing with it for a few and couldn't figure out why. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

this can be done in pure CSS (*not even 3*).

On hover have a tilted background image, position it a few pixel to the left and top and add background color.

Because of the background color, you will see only a part of the image:

```
<div class="text">Screenings</div>

.text {
  color: #000;
  margin-left: 5px;/*to make room for the hover image */
  padding: 4px;
}
.text:hover {
  background: #900 url(tiltedimage.png) no-repeat -5px -5px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

This will point you to the solution.